# How to cancel a blocking OpenGL call

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpgpu

I'm investigating GPGPU programming with OpenGL + GLSL. One problem is that if you have a shader that takes a long time to finish, it seems to be impossible to cancel it.

After setting up everything, I issue the final `glReadPixels` call which blocks until all pixels have been rendered to a framebuffer. Depending on the shader, this could take a long time, even seconds. Is there a way to cancel the call (from another thread) or even query the progress? What happens if you set up an infinite loop in a shader?

Comment: the correct answer would be that blocking a OpenGL blocking call is not possible (this is actually an issue because some people have shaders that do long computations) from user space. Basically the operative system give OpenGL "some time". If openGL does not end the work in time, the operative system just kill the process. However you already accepted an answer so good luck anyway:D

Comment: See my reply, I've basically just given up on it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of glReadPixels you could use PixelBufferObjects which are not blocking. glReadPixels will wait (in your main thread) for the results, but PBO will continue... somewhere later in the code you can check if the data in PBO are available.

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object

if you need some more advanced calculations then you may want to use OpenCL, that will give you more flexibility.

Comment: +1 for PBO.It is also called "async transfer" For me it improved texture download up to 80% .

Comment: Looks like a PBO in combination with a fence would to the trick... but I need this to work on OpenGL ES 2.0 as well for the iPad (this is also why I don't use OpenCL). But a good answer anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if you set up an infinite loop in a shader?

I think you will get crash of video driver.

Comment: Downvoted because "I think" does not mean anything. I just tried it on an older ATI card and the driver here terminates the shader if it runs too long on a per-pixel basis, without any error reporting. Possibly this is vendor-specific.

Comment: I experimented some more and the driver indeed crashes after two seconds on Windows Vista because Windows forces it to. I'm still keeping the downvote because of "I think": you didn't provide a good explanation of why the crash would happen.

Comment: This case is not described in documentation. I have experience when I have crash with very slow shaders (I think, it was connected with http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3007, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487368.aspx). Also I have crash, if my shader read many data from texture (about 1000 read operation). I wanted to write a comment under question about "I think", but I cannot write comment.

Comment: It depends on operative system not on drivers, and edited version of this answer (without "I Think" ) should be accepted.