# Modern way to stream pixels to OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, streaming, pixel

I have a system that composites 5 megapixel images in real-time. Everything works, but I want to visualize my feed with an OpenGL program.

What is the best way to draw a `char*` of rgb to the screen? I was hoping to use OpenGL to perform GPU interop, although any suggestions as to platform would also help.

There is a simliar post here [OpenGL - draw pixels to screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825011/opengl-draw-pixels-to-screen) but it seems that the method is dated and link to glDrawPixels is dead.

Comment: I've fixed that link. Yes, it's dated and it's been removed in new API (which is why the link got broken in the first place)

Comment: About your question, have you tried to simply make a texture and update it via `glTexSubImage2D`?

Comment: @Kos I am currently trying a few experiments, but I feel this is solved problem. I don't like the idea of having a box with a texture rendered on it because I feel that there is computational inefficiency going from model coordinates to the view port coordinates. If this handled in hardware it guess it doesn't matter. Finally, I am not sure about the DMA which is important as my application is currently consuming a Xeon X7560

Comment: @Mikhail: "I don't like the idea of having a box with a texture rendered on it because I feel that there is computational inefficiency going from model coordinates to the view port coordinates." – actually drawing a textured quad is the most efficient way to splat images to the OpenGL framebuffer. It allows the GPU to use texture caches and fetch hardware. I know, it's counterintuitive, but that's how it is. You mentioned "interop". If you're using OpenCL or CUDA, you can write into a texture object directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copied from my previous answer:  [How to cancel a blocking OpenGL call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071350/how-to-cancel-a-blocking-opengl-call)

instead of glDrawPixels you could use PixelBufferObjects which are not blocking. glDrawPixels will wait (in your main thread) until whole pixel transfer is finished, but PBO will continue...

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object

if you need some more advanced calculations then you may want to use OpenCL, that will give you more flexibility.

Comment: Are pixel buffer objects modern?

Comment: good question, but I think they are modern. PBO was introduced in opengl 2.1 (so this is old), but they add modern usage to the opengl - that means using buffers. I do not know if there is something better to use (even with opengl 4.3) right now.

Comment: I guess you are correct, it might not be the most advanced way but it is certainly not obsolete.

Comment: you can check OpenCL, maybe it has some better way of streaming data to the GPU, but it is "outside" of OpenGL.